# Aegir upgrade step on ubtunu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, aegir

In Aegir 7.x.3.11, We are using the PHP 5.6 version in ubuntu 14.04 in which we have drupal 7 & 8 sites.

While upgrading the PHP version, the PHP repository is not supported for this ubuntu version.

So we planned to upgrade ubuntu 18.04 with Aegir's latest version.

Needs steps to upgrade latest Aegir on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

While [the official upgrade guide](https://docs.aegirproject.org/install/upgrade/) doesn't mention it, most of us do the following (as it's the safest):

1. Set up a new clean Aegir installation on a new VM.
2. Remotely import your sites by enabling [the Remote Import module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_remote_import) (it ships with Aegir) on the new Aegir installation.
3. Import each site from the old Aegir server.

If you've got Ubuntu 20.04, you should be aware of [Create an Aegir 3.20 release for recent stable Debian & Ubuntu LTS](https://www.drupal.org/project/hostmaster/issues/3246691).